# R regular expressions, trying to capture a group

Tags: regex, r

I've read a few of the other questions on R capture groups in regular expressions and i'm not having much luck.

I have a string:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Dec/2014:06:43:43 -0800] \"OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0\" 200 - \"-\" \"Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.24 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8k mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 (internal dummy connection)\"
```

From which I am trying to capture a timestamp:

```
07/Dec/2014:06:43:43 -0800
```

The following function invocation returns a match:

```
regmatches(x,regexpr('\\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\]',x,perl=TRUE))
[1] "[07/Dec/2014:06:43:43 -0800]"
```

I've tried to capture the single group itself with str_match with varying varieties of this regex:

```
str_match(x, "\\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\]")
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] NA   NA
```

To no avail.  Varying varieties of this regex test correctly in most of the online regex testers so I don't think the regex is the problem.

How can I get just the timestamp itself so I can pump it into strptime, without doing something like `gsub` the brackets?  gsub doesn't work to get the group for me, str_match doesn't work, what am I missing?  The ideal output would be

```
07/Dec/2014:06:43:43 -0800
```

which I could then use in strptime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`\k`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) (*`\K` keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match.*) and a positive lookahead.

```
> regmatches(x,regexpr('\\[\\K[\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4}(?=\\])',x,perl=TRUE))
[1] "07/Dec/2014:06:43:43 -0800"
```

`\\K` in `\\[\\K` discards the previously matched `[` character.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=\[)([\w:\/]+\s[+\-]\d{4})(?=\])
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/16

Comment: The regex isn't the problem, I don't think.  Getting the match from R is.

Comment: @Arima this should get you what you want

Comment: You just need to add additional backslash for everywhere where there is a stored letter such as `s`, `w` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `qdapRegex` package it has a special method for extracting elements from square brackets

```
library(qdapRegex)
rm_square(x, extract = TRUE)[[1]]
## [1] "07/Dec/2014:06:43:43 -0800"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy with `sub`. You can replace the whole string with the matching group.

```
sub(".*\\[([A-z0-9:/]+\\s[+-]\\d{4})\\].*", "\\1", x)
# [1] "07/Dec/2014:06:43:43 -0800"
```